# Galera: Cannot write to database when indexing large data

Tags: mysql, database-indexes, galera

I am using  Galera Cluster with 3 nodes. I am currently meet following problems. I want to write more than 500 millions of records into database, for example table Data. Here is following steps:

- Create table NewData with schema as Data but without index.
- Write 500 millions records into this table. (using multiple threads to write, each thread will write bunch of records).
- After finishing, assign index for this table.
- Rename Data to OldData and rename NewData to Data.

The problem I am currently have is at indexing phrase, other services cannot write / read data. After I increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` other nodes can read data but still cannot write.

I have configured so that written job writes at different node than other api's but problem still the same. I think that if one node is very high workload, other node should still behave normally. Please tell me why and how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you missed a step.

1. (one-time) Create table `NewData` with schema as `Data` but without index.
2. Insert into `NewData`.
3. Create table `Empty (again like Data but without any index)
4. `RENAME TABLE NewData TO ToIndex, Empty TO NewData;`  -- Now the ingestion can proceed.
5. `ALTER TABLE ToIndex ADD INDEX ...`
6. `RENAME TABLE Data TO Old, ToIndex TO Data;`

The point is to have two things going on:

- Continually writing to the unindexed `NewData`.
- Swap tables around so that periodically that table (under a new name) gets indexed, and then used to replace the live table (which is always seen as `Data`).

This is not quite the same situation, but has some similarities:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table